# Advanced wicket programming

Tags: java, wicket, scalability

I am currently involved in a medium-scale (300-400k lines) project written in Apache Wicket. At this time, majority of it's source code is not really reusable, breaks a lot of wicket's "best practices" (like passing raw objects instead of models or passing whole components/pages to other components), it's prone to all kinds of errors and does not handle extending functionality well. As far as Wicket's documentation goes, it is great way to scratch the surface, but I can not really say it's sufficient source of information for projects of this scale. What I am interested in is, how large scale applications are actually written in Wicket? Are there any sources/examples you could recommend?
And as for something specific, I also have few questions:

- How to handle communication between several components? Are events preferred over abstract/no-op methods or vice versa?
- Are anonymous implementations considered bad practice? How to establish a boundary on what should stay in a component and what should go into services (ie. when overriding onClick())?
- How to properly encapsulate component functionality, if it depends on other components?
- How to avoid conditional adding of componenta (ie. if(...) add.(A) else add(B))? Is there any other way around this except setting either one to visible=false?

I would really wish to dig deeper into wicket and take few more steps to mastering it, but I feel like there is not much to learn from.

Thank you in advance for your answers, anything will be appreciated :)

Comment: @gla3dr this question is too broad regardless of the site on which it is asked: we have the same close reason on Programmers.SE. Please read: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/22815)**.

Comment: @Snowman Yeah it's pretty broad and I'm not a regular user of Programmers.SE which is why I wasn't sure. I had a look at the "What topics can I ask about here" in your help center before posting but I guess I was still wrong. Thanks for the link though!

Comment: @gla3dr regardless of what is considered on-topic, each SE site requires a question to have reasonable scope and not be open-ended. A question must also be clear, and not purely a matter of opinion. Those are universal across all sites, which is why most (if not all) sites have "too broad, unclear, primary opinion-based" as close reasons.

Comment: There is a list of sites made with Wicket: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Websites+based+on+Wicket or http://builtwithwicket.tumblr.com/

Comment: These are good questions, but there are too many of them packaged into one. You can ask them one by one or even better, read [Wicket in Action](http://wicketinaction.com/), which covers most of these areas very well.

Comment: Though on second thought, Wicket in Action seems not to have been updated for a long time, so maybe not.